# XSD file creates nested static class using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm new to JAXB and and fairly new to JAVA.  I created JAXB classes from XSD file using Eclipse built in functionality by right clicking on the XSD file.

But what I ended up with is a class that has a nested static inner class.

Now here's the problem:  I'm trying to Marshal and create XML file.  But how do I pass the nested inner class along with the outer class.

```
public class OuterClass {

String x = "None of the methods or variables are static in the inner our outer class";

public static class InnerClass{

}
```

}

XML: should look like this

```
<OuterClass RequestType="LogOn" ApplicationSender="Example"
WorkstationID="001">
<InnerClass>
    <TimeStamp>2 009-11-20T17:30:50</TimeStamp>
    <InterfaceVersion>01.00</InterfaceVersion>
</InnerClass>
```

There is also a closing  tag but for some reason in the preview it's not showing up.

Here's the actual XSD file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--IFSF POS-FDC Schema 23 November 2010-->

<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:include schemaLocation="FDC_Basic_Types.xsd"/>
<xs:include schemaLocation="FDC_DR_CurrencyCode_Full.xsd"/>

<xs:element name="ServiceRequest">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="POSdata">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="POSTimeStamp" type="specialtime"/>
                        <xs:element name="InterfaceVersion" type="InterfaceVersion"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="RequestType" type="RequestType" fixed="LogOn" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="ApplicationSender" type="ApplicationSender" use="required" />           
            <xs:attribute name="WorkstationID" type="WorkstationID" use="required" />      
            <xs:attribute name="RequestID" type="RequestID" use="required" />      
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here's the class that it creates:

```
    <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="POSdata">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="POSTimeStamp" type="{}specialtime"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="InterfaceVersion" type="{}InterfaceVersion"/>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="RequestType" use="required" type="{}RequestType" fixed="LogOn" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="ApplicationSender" use="required" type="{}ApplicationSender" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="WorkstationID" use="required" type="{}WorkstationID" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="RequestID" use="required" type="{}RequestID" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ServiceRequest")
public class ServiceRequest {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "POSdata", type = JAXBElement.class)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "RequestType", required = true)
    protected RequestType requestType;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ApplicationSender", required = true)
    protected String applicationSender;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "WorkstationID", required = true)
    protected String workstationID;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "RequestID", required = true)
    protected String requestID;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getContent().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ServiceRequest.POSdata }{@code >}
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the requestType property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link RequestType }
     *     
     */
    public RequestType getRequestType() {
        if (requestType == null) {
            return RequestType.LOG_ON;
        } else {
            return requestType;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the requestType property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link RequestType }
     *     
     */
    public void setRequestType(RequestType value) {
        this.requestType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the applicationSender property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getApplicationSender() {
        return applicationSender;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the applicationSender property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setApplicationSender(String value) {
        this.applicationSender = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the workstationID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getWorkstationID() {
        return workstationID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the workstationID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setWorkstationID(String value) {
        this.workstationID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the requestID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getRequestID() {
        return requestID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the requestID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setRequestID(String value) {
        this.requestID = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="POSTimeStamp" type="{}specialtime"/>
     *         &lt;element name="InterfaceVersion" type="{}InterfaceVersion"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "posTimeStamp",
        "interfaceVersion"
    })
    public static class POSdata {

        @XmlElement(name = "POSTimeStamp", required = true)
        protected String posTimeStamp;
        @XmlElement(name = "InterfaceVersion", required = true)
        protected String interfaceVersion;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the posTimeStamp property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getPOSTimeStamp() {
            return posTimeStamp;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the posTimeStamp property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setPOSTimeStamp(String value) {
            this.posTimeStamp = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the interfaceVersion property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getInterfaceVersion() {
            return interfaceVersion;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the interfaceVersion property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setInterfaceVersion(String value) {
            this.interfaceVersion = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete edit:

You are supposed to add the instance wrapped in a JAXBElement into the `content` list.

To create the wrapped `JAXBElemen<POSdata>` instance you can/should use the factory method inside the also created `ObjectFactory`.

So something like this:

```
ServiceRequest.POSdata pos = new ServiceRequest.POSdata();
// fill in some data
JAXBElement<POSdata> posElement =  new ObjectFactory().createPOSdataElement(pos);  // I might be a bit off with the method name, there should be one with that signature.

request.getContent().add(posElement);
```

Comment: I wish I could do that.  But there is no method in the outer class to set the inner class. Also I do not want to edit the auto generated class.

Comment: Please paste the actual code and the actual xsd that was used to generate that code.

Comment: I've edited the original post and added the code in.  Thanks

Comment: I tried following your directions.  First thing I looked up was the format made sure everything was correct.  Found another similar example at this site http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071784/enterprise-java/java-xml-mapping-made-easy-with-jaxb-2-0.html   But when I try to implement the same thing eclipse keeps giving me an error:   The method createPOSdata(ServiceRequest.POSdata) is undefined for the type Object  Any suggestions?

Comment: So you dont have an `ObjectFactory` ?

Comment: Found out what I was doing wrong.  Since the inner nested class was static the method that I was calling was not available because it was named a bit different.  Eclipse kept offering me to cast and when I did that It was throwing an error.  Also my import for object factory came from some sun package. After correcting that and changing JAXBElement line to this: JAXBElement<POSdata> posElement = new ObjectFactory().createServiceRequestPOSdata(object2); I was able to make it work.  Thanks for the help